# Sidekiq no retries on class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

I'm calling the Sidekiq delay on a class method like:

```
Class.delay.some_method()
```

This works well except when there are errors because I cannot set the retries to false. Any advice on this?

The documentation shows retries for non-class methods (worker): https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling

How do I set the retries to false for a class method without needing to convert it to a worker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually do this

```
Class.delay(:retry => false).some_method()
```

Documentation [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions#wiki-advanced-options)